# How to view query history in datagrip when the icon is not available?

Tags: datagrip

[On the datagrip website:](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/executing.html)

> On the toolbar of every console there is a [button](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/img/console/HistoryIcon.png). Press it to
> see the history of all the queries which were run against this data
> source. Speed search also works!
>
> Also, don't forget about the Local History of each file.

But I do not see this icon. So how can I make this visible?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can browse query history either by clicking an icon(watch) or by invoking shortcut `Option+Command+E`

[image: Browse Query History icon]

Detailed description one could find in [DataGrip documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/run-a-query.html#executing_memorized_statements)